# how can I get spreadsheet by url ? and then write the values I get into some other sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a template google file that I have modified, and now, I would like to apply those modification to all the spreadsheet that I have already create from this template.

1 - so I would like to get the values from a closed spreadsheet like that :

`var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("https://docs.google.com/....the template adress").getSheetByName("LEGENDE PROJET").getRange([A6],[I2:I]).getValues();`

of course I know that   `.getActiveSpreadsheet("https://docs.google.com/....the template adress")` will not be the good way to do it.

So what would be the good class ?

because when I read this :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=fr#getui
I don't find a way to do it.

2 - Then I would like to replace the values in the exact same ranges in a list of sheets by url. Will I have to open all of them one by one with `openByUrl(url)` or can I wrote into them without opening it ?

Answer (score 2):

To open an existing Google Sheet using Apps Script, you can use the `openByUrl()` method (e.g.):

```
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/google_sheet_ID/edit');
  let sheet = soruce_sheet.getSheetByName('LEGENDE PROJET');
```

You can read more information about this method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl).

Depending on how many ranges you want to take the values from, you can use `getRangeList()` for several ranges in the same sheet, this creates a list of ranges that you can later iterate into or for a few ranges or ranges in different `sheets` you can create 1 variable for each range. For 2 ranges, I will use a variable for each range.

```
  // for few values on the same sheet
  let value_1 = sheet.getRange('A6').getValue();
  let value_2 = sheet.getRange('I2:I').getValues();
```

Or

```
  // get the values from the source sheet with the range where the values are located
  let range_list = sheet.getRangeList(['A6', 'I2:I', 'B2', 'G2:G']).getRanges();
  
  range_list.forEach((range) => {
    let value = range.getValues()
  })
```

Then you can add the list of URLs of the Google Sheet in the code, or add them to a Google sheet and use the same method of `getValues()` to get the list of URLs from there.

```
  // add manually the list of URLs 
  let list_of_sheets = ['url_1', 'url_2',
    'url_3', 'url_4', 'url_5', 'url_6'];
```

Lastly, you will need to paste the values in the new sheets, using the method `setValue()`.

Here is a working sample code you can use as reference, you can modify it as necessary:

```
function copy_and_replace() {

  //the template with the new information that will be copy on the list of sheets
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/google_sheet_ID/edit');
  
  // replace with the name of the sheet. 
  let source_sheet = soruce_Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LEGENDE PROJET');

  // for few values on the same sheet
  let source_value_1 = source_sheet.getRange('A6').getValue();
  let source_value_2 = source_sheet.getRange('I2:I').getValues();

  // add manually the list of URLs 
  let list_of_sheets =   let list_of_sheets = ['url_1', 'url_2',
    'url_3', 'url_4', 'url_5', 'url_6'];

  // iterate to all the values in the list, to past the new data
  list_of_sheets.forEach((url) => {
    let target_Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    let target_sheet = target_Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    target_sheet.getRange('A6').setValue(source_value_1);
    target_sheet.getRange('I2:I').setValues(source_value_2)
  });

}
```

**Reference:**

- Using the `Class SpreadsheetApp` with the method [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- Using the `Class Spreadsheet` with the method [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) or [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations)
- Using the `Class Range` with the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) & [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- Also, from the `Class Range` [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) & [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)